# When execution plan is changed for DELETE TOP(X) in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-execution-plan, sql-server-2017

I observe a little strange behavior in Microsoft SQL Server 2017.
When I `DELETE` data row by row:

```
DELETE TOP(1) 
FROM [table_A] 
WHERE [id] IN (SELECT [i] FROM [table_B])
```

it takes about 4 min. (11GB database)

**but** when I execute:

```
DELETE TOP(1000) 
FROM [table_A] 
WHERE [id] IN (SELECT [i] FROM [table_B])
```

on the same table, execution is very fast (<< 1 second).

Difference is in execution plan.

**Question:** how to force SQL Server to use the execution plan from the second statement (`DELETE TOP(**1000**) ...`) for the first statement (`DELETE TOP(**1**) ...`)?

see:

[image]

Comment: Upload the actual execution plans to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and add the links to your question.

Comment: I can upload only screenshot from SQL Management Studio

Answer (score 1):

> *Question: how to force SQL Server to use the execution plan from the second statement (DELETE TOP(**1000**) ...) for the first statement (DELETE TOP(**1**) ...)?*

You could force specific join type with hint:

```
DELETE TOP(1) FROM [table_A] 
WHERE [id] IN (SELECT [i] FROM [table_B]) 
-- OPTION(LOOP JOIN);
-- OPTION(HASH JOIN);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=13e9c144897c5965c137792e05730f4a)**